# Email is not sent in RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I want to send mail from my ruby on rails application and I follow the below steps:

First I create mailer using below command:

```
rails generate mailer UserMailer
```

I am doing below in `user_mailer.rb` page:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "xxxxx@xxxxx.com"

  def schedule
    @mail_to = 'abc@gmail.com' #params[:Schedule][:Appointments]
    mail :to => @mail_to, :subject => "Hi"
  end
end
```

And `schedule` is my view page `schedule.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for(:Schedule,:html => {:id => "Schedule"}) do |f| %>
    <table class="table" width="100%">
        <th><font size="+1">Interview Schedule</font></th>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label style="font-size:small; font-weight:bold;">Send Appointments to:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= f.text_field :mail_to_address, :style => "font-size:small;" %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:top;">
                <label style="font-size:small; font-weight:bold;">Message:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= f.text_area :message, :style => "font-size:small; width:300px; height:100px;" %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= f.submit "Send", { :style => "font-size:small" } %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<% end %>
```

In the above code `mail_to_address` text_field I put email address where I want to send email and put some text in the `message` text_field and click on `Send` button, but the mail is not sending. why?

And, below is the `environment.rb` page code:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
VideoResume::Application.initialize!
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => "gmail.com",
    :authentication => :login,
    :charset => 'utf-8',
    :user_name => "abc@gmail.com",
    :password => "password"
}
```

and In my App/config/environments/development.rb I have:

```
VideoResume::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

Kindly suggest me what I should do, waiting for reply.
Thanks

Comment: and.... what happens when you try to send an email?

Comment: Do you call `UserMailer.schedule.deliver` method in result action?

Comment: you have not given controller code here. your mailer looks fine. To send email you just need to call UserMailer.schedule.deliver somewhere in controller action or in model correspondent to your form submission.

Comment: @ mixan946: no, How do I call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From at the comments above i think the **problem is that you are not calling your mailer method**. As `@mixian945` and `@Sachin` pointed out you need to call your mailer.

Lets suppose you want to send a mail from **create_schedule method** in your controller then you can send it by

```
def create_schedule
  # your method logic
  UserMailer.schedule.deliver #this will call your schedule method in UserMailer class and hence send your mail
end

def schedule
  mail to: "abc@gmail.com", subject: "Hi"
end
```

---

Also *if you want to send users id or something to your deliver method* then you can call your schedule method like

```
def create_schedule
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) #your logic to find your user
  # your method logic
  UserMailer.schedule.deliver(@user.email)
end
```

this will allow you to have your method like

```
def schedule (email)
  mail :to => email, :subject => "Hi"
end
```

For details refer to [**`Action Mailer Basics`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)

Comment: I want to send email to me at this email address `abc@gmail.com`. Is it possible?

Comment: @user3800418 yeah!! updated my answer check the first half, you need to hardcode it inside your schedule method by `mail to: "abc@gmail.com", subject: "Hi"`

Comment: I have a problem that, my `schedule` page is inside a `managers` tree and managers have a controller, and in the managers controller I add `schedule` method and schedule also in the `user_mailer.rb` then what can I do?

Comment: @user3800418 first of all read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html for basics and you need to have your mailer template inside `views/user_mailer/' also if you have same methods then it shouldn't be any problem since you are calling it by class name like `UserMailer.schedule`. DO READ THE BASICS FIRST in link

Answer (score 0):

**Delivery**

Bottom line is when you create a `mailer` in ROR, [you'll have to `deliver` it somehow](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#class-ActionMailer%3a%3aBase-label-Sending+mail)

As you can [see here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#class-ActionMailer%3a%3aBase-label-Sending+mail), you'll basically have to call the mailer & the `.deliver` method to get the thing sent. This is in parallel to your declaration of the mailer itself:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
   def action
      @mailer = UserMailer.schedule
      @mailer.deliver
   end
end
```

--

**Settings**

This, obviously, needs to have a series of settings in order to get it to work properly. We use `gmail`'s SMTP settings for testing in development:

```
#config/environments/development.rb
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => 587,
      :domain               => "testdomain.com",
      :user_name            => "test@gmail.com",
      :password             => Rails.application.secrets.gmail,
      :authentication       => :plain,
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
      :host => "localhost"
}
```

This will allow you to send the messages through `gmail`'s servers - the above is working code